# colorbox not working

Tags: colorbox

I am tring to add colorbox to the "Keep up to date box" at the bottom of the pages of this site so that the form pops up

http://www.hadleygreenclothing.co.uk/index.php

When you click it you get k is undefined. Can someone tell me why please.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This might not entirely solve the problem, but you should only include the source to colorbox a single time.  The jquery.colorbox.js and jquery.colorbox-min.js are the same code, it is just that the 2nd one has been minimized for a smaller file size.  Also, maybe I overlooked it but I did not see where the CSS for colorbox was included in the document.

Comment: Colorbox being included twice on the page seems to be the cause of this issue (K is undefined)

Comment: "Colorbox being included twice on the page seems to be the cause of this issue (K is undefined)" --- This solved my problem. Thnku sooo much!